# Apps refuse to sync on Macbook Pro after enabling child account screen time limits

Tags: macos, screen-time

So I've recently created a child Apple ID using my friend's iPhone as a parent device in order to then log in as a child on my Mac and iPad and set up screen time limits since my device addiction is impossible to rein in any other way.

All had been jolly good until recently I've noticed how all the apps installed on my Mac refuse to sync with the servers or install updates. I'm especially concerned about Anki and Todoist, the two apps I rely on the most for my studies.

The first time I'm seeing this, and it all began right after I had set the limits from my friend's iPhone. It is definitely caused by the child account limits.

Does anyone know how to solve this failure to sync ?

Comment: Is anki a flashcard program? My hunch is you have issues unrelated to parental controls since that blocks the app from running in the gui and not any background  sync process. If you can run the app, parental controls is likely not causing an issue.

Comment: @bmike Thanks for the response. It is definitely caused by it. I've just disabled the screen time limits and rebooted the laptop. And boom, everything syncs perfectly. Let's assume the parental controls are to blame, what should I do? I so do want to leave them in place but they render apps impossible to use.

Comment: If you can make it happen, open a support case with Apple and send some logs. I bet they don’t intend that or have guidance for you.